# Get original files from Subversion directory copied from server

Tags: apache, svn, ubuntu

I had an old server. I copied the the folder where all the files for a project were located. I want to restore the original files.

I tried an svn export on the directory, but that did not work. It said that it is not a working copy. Is there a command that I can use on the directory to get the files back?

Here are the commands I ran:

```
C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Server Old>svn export JCS_R3
svn: E155007: 'C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Server Old\JCS_R3' is not a working copy

C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Server Old>cd JCS_R3

C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Server Old\JCS_R3>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 2A6F-89F3

 Directory of C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Server Old\JCS_R3

04/30/2012  06:55 PM              .
04/30/2012  06:55 PM              ..
04/30/2012  06:55 PM              conf
04/30/2012  06:55 PM              dav
04/30/2012  06:55 PM              db
02/03/2011  01:35 PM                 2 format
04/30/2012  06:55 PM              hooks
04/30/2012  06:55 PM              locks
02/03/2011  01:35 PM               229 README.txt
               2 File(s)            231 bytes
               7 Dir(s)  218,980,196,352 bytes free
```

It was running on an Ubuntu Server using Apache. Not sure if that matters or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got here is a copy of the *repository*, not of a *working copy*. If you successfully copied everything then all your files (and all the revision history) should be in there. You could try something like this:

```
svn checkout "file:///C:/Users/Dan/Desktop/Server Old/JCS_R3"
```

(note: your current directory should be somewhere else when you do this, so that you don't try to put a working copy inside your repository!)

I don't know whether it will be a problem that the repository was on a Unix machine and you're now on Windows. If so, you may have more success if you copy it onto another Unix box.

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly. Thanks so much. You cant even imagine the sigh of relief. thought everything was lost.

Comment: I know that feeling well. I'm glad it's sorted! (You should probably accept my answer if it solved your problem.)